# VLookup in Excel vba not working

Tags: vba, excel

[Excel File Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RX03.png)

I have master data table with attribute ID which is unique and unit.
I have another table where I add the product values associated with the attributes.

If the units match based on the attribute ID, then the cells are highlighted in green else red.

To achieve the above, I have written some basic code, but it doesn't seem to work. The vlookup works normally but using vba it just exits.  Please see image for example and code below. Column a and b contains attribute master data and column d to g contain product attribute values.

Eg. For product p1, value 'IN' is valid for attribute 'A1' but 'm' is not valid.
Also, there can be multiple units separated by comma for each attribute. Need help to solve issue.

Code:

```
Sub UnitCheck()


Dim AttrIDrange As range, AttrIDcell As range
Dim attrID
Dim Lookup_Range As range
Dim I, J As Variant
Dim UNIT As Variant
Set Lookup_Range = range("A2:B4")

Set AttrIDrange = range("E1:G1")


For Each AttrIDcell In AttrIDrange
attrID = AttrIDcell.Value


For I = 2 To 3
For J = 5 To 7

If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(attrID, Lookup_Range, 2, False) = UNIT Then
    Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(I, J).Font.Color = vbGreen

    Else
     Worksheets("Sheet4").Cells(I, J).Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
Next
Next
Next

End Sub
```

**New Scenario:**
If there are multiple units defined for any attribute, then even if only 1 of the unit is present in the product value, it should be highlighed in green. If 1 is correct and rest are incorrect then since it is partially correct, it should be highlighted in red or even yellow. Please see image. Need help for this scenario.

[Scenario 2 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RX03.png)

Comment: I fail to see where `UNIT` is assigned a value before being compared to the returned value from the VLookup.

Comment: Im just comparing the unit for now excluding the value

Comment: I'll try to be clearer; UNIT is nothing and cannot be compared to the result of a formula.

Comment: Accept answers then ask a new question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum  "Stack Overflow is not a forum. Forums are largely discussion-based and tend to follow less strict rules about what posts can be like.

On Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general), we require every new thread to be started with a question and every response to that question to be an attempt at answering it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that I think does what the OP is asking. Also, this replaces the triple `For/next` and VLookUp with a dictionary which is hopefully more amenable.

In regard to the OP, I see two fundamental problems, UNIT is never assigned, but also, it sounds like the `=` operator isn't correct... instead, it sounds like a lookup value must be confirmed present in a comma separated string. The code below uses `InStr` to check if the lookup value is present.

```
Sub UnitCheck()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim UNIT As String
Dim R, c, AttrID   As Integer
Dim ProdRange, ProdCell As Range
Set ProdRange = Range("E2:G4")

'Assign LookUp values to array
Dim LookUpArray(), ProdAttrIDArray() As Variant
LookUpArray = Range("A2:B4").Value2

'Create dictionary from Lookup values
Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For R = 1 To UBound(LookUpArray)
    D.Add LookUpArray(R, 1), LookUpArray(R, 2)
Next

'Loop through product table
For Each ProdCell In ProdRange
    'Get attribute ID from row 1 of corresponding column
    AttrID = Cells(1, ProdCell.Column).Value2
    If D(AttrID) <> Empty Then
        'If AttrID found in LookUp Dictionary then get UNIT from it
        UNIT = D(AttrID)
        'If UNIT found in product cell then color cell green, else red
        If (InStr(1, ProdCell.Value2, UNIT) > 0) Then
            ProdCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
        Else
            ProdCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

The result is this

[image]

### New Scenario

Ok, I think this will cover your new scenario. Notice that I also added `Trim()` and `VBTextCompare` so that spaces are ignored and the comparison is case-insensitive. I'm not sure if you want that behavior or not. Also, notice that the order of units does not matter. For example, "IN,   km" matches "KM, IN" because the spaces are ignored, capitalization is ignored, and the order is ignored.

```
Sub UnitCheck()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim UNIT, PUnits() As String
    Dim r, c, AttrID, i, n As Integer
    Dim ProdRange, ProdCell As Range
    Set ProdRange = Range("E2:G3")

    'Assign LookUp values to array
    Dim LookUpArray(), ProdAttrIDArray() As Variant
    LookUpArray = Range("A2:B4").Value2

    'Create dictionary from Lookup values
    Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For r = 1 To UBound(LookUpArray)
        D.Add LookUpArray(r, 1), LookUpArray(r, 2)
    Next

    'Loop through product table
    For Each ProdCell In ProdRange
        'Get attribute ID from row 1 of correspdniong column
        AttrID = Cells(1, ProdCell.Column).Value2
        If D(AttrID) <> Empty Then
            'If AttrID found in LoopUp Dictionary then get UNIT from it
            UNIT = D(AttrID)
            PUnits = Split(ProdCell.Value2, ",")
            'reset counter
            n = 0
            'Count the number of product units found in the lookup value
            For i = 0 To UBound(PUnits)
                If InStr(1, Trim(UNIT), Trim(PUnits(i)), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    n = n + 1
                End If
            Next
            'prevent division by zero
            If i = 0 Then i = 1
            'select action based on percent matched
            Select Case n / i
                Case Is >= 1
                    ProdCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
                Case Is > 0
                     ProdCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                Case Else
                    ProdCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            End Select

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Need help for the updated scenario.
[Img 2][2]
 [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2Icc1.png

Comment: @Renee Ok, I updated my answer per the new scenario 2.

Answer (score 1):

When cycling through the I and J loops, you need to set **UNIT** to something before you can compare it to the results passed back from the worksheet [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65).

```
Sub UnitCheck()
    Dim AttrIDrange As Range, AttrIDcell As Range
    Dim attrID
    Dim Lookup_Range As Range
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim UNIT As Variant
    Dim bCHECK_P1

    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        bCHECK_P1 = False
        Set Lookup_Range = .Range("A2:B4")
        Set AttrIDrange = .Range("E1:G1")

        For Each AttrIDcell In AttrIDrange  '.Range("E1:G1")
            attrID = AttrIDcell.Value

            For I = 2 To 3
                UNIT = AttrIDcell.Offset(I - 1, 0).Value  '<~~ set UNIT here!
                For J = 5 To 7
                    .Cells(I, J).Font.Color = xlAutomatic
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(attrID, Lookup_Range, 2, False) = UNIT Then
                        .Cells(I, J).Font.Color = vbGreen
                    Else
                         .Cells(I, J).Font.Color = vbRed
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You. I slightly modified the code as mentioned below as the vlookup didnt work as the attrID and UNIT didn't increment. It works now. Need help for the updated scenario